# How to join two formulas in one delimited text cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to join two formulas on one cell.

For example I have these two formulas

```
=sum(1+1)
=multiply(1,5)
```

How can I combine them in one cell delimited by | ?

Answer (score 4):

There is `concatenate` which takes multiple parameters, so only one call is needed:

```
=concatenate(sum(1+1), "|", multiply(1,5))
```

Even shorter is the binary concatenation operator `&`, which is what I would use:

```
=sum(1+1) & "|" & multiply(1,5)
```

Comment: Wow, the binary concat operator works well! An example, which abuses sum to build a range cell.  ```=SUM(B6,0)  & " - " & SUM(C6,0)```

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 `CONCAT` calls.

```
=CONCAT(SUM(1+1), CONCAT("|", MULTIPLY(1,5))
```